# Dropdownlist and validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, dropdown

I have 2 tables, the first is `Students` with 3 fields (name, firstname, fk_diploma).Then, my second table is named `Diplomas` and there is 1 field named (type_diploma).

For information, I have 3 records in my field `type_diploma`:

```
1) DiplomaA
2) DiplomaB
3) DiplomaC
```

In my validate system, the User can choose the DiplomaA or DiplomaB but not the DiplomaC, If the user chooses `DiplomaC`, an error message appears

For example: * "Sorry, you do not have the skills for the diplomaC."

[image]

is there a solution in laravel?

```
public function store(studentRequest $request)
    {      
       $exists = Student::where('name', $request->get('name'))->where('firstname', $request->get('firstname'))->where('fk_diploma', $request->get('fk_diploma'))->count();

       if (!$exists){
            Student::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

        else{
            return redirect()->route('students.index')
                ->with('error', 'duplicate');

        }   

}
```

Comment: Not sure what your error is - are you trying to show the error via a Javascript response based on 'bad' diploma ids ?  Can you show the code for that if so to see what specifically is breaking?

Comment: @Watercayman: I want to do that in Laravel. My problem is that I do not know how to do ??

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I don't think I can answer that simply here.  I think what you are looking for though, is to create an array of IDs that will have a negative response.  When the user attempts to click on those 'bad' ids (of diploma types), javascript fires and sends the message.  I think from here, do a little research on JS or jquery for on-click, alerts (or modal pop-ups), and how to send data to that code to get what you want :)